# Cannot copy text in Emacs and paste into another application

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm running GNU Linux and GNU Emacs 23.4.2

When I copy text in Emacs (with <kbd>M-w</kbd>, or in CUA mode <kbd>C-c</kbd>) and then type <kbd>C-v</kbd> in some other application to try to paste the copied text, it doesn't work -- the text from Emacs is not pasted.

However, when I instead copy the text using the Emacs **menus** (Edit->Copy), this works -- I can successfully paste the copied text into another application with <kbd>C-v</kbd>.

How can I fix this, so that copying via the keybindings works the same as copying via the menus?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by "it works only inside emacs". Changes to your Emacs keybindings will not affect any other application, and I'm at a loss as to why you would think that they might. (If that's not what you meant, perhaps you could re-phrase / clarify that part?)

Comment: added explanation to question

Comment: I don't understand the explanation either, I'm afraid. Maybe it's getting lost in translation. If no one else can help, some screenshots would probably be a good idea.

Comment: simply when I copy something using C-c I can't paste it wherever instead of emacs. I don't think that I can make screenshot with it.

Comment: So the problem is that when you copy text in Emacs and then type `C-v` in a different application, the copied text is not pasted? And this *only* happens with CUA mode enabled? (i.e. if CUA is off and you use `M-w` to copy the text, then pasting into another application works?). And are you saying that things *do* work the way you want when you use the menus? Lastly, what platform/version are you using (e.g. Windows? OSX?), and which version of Emacs are you running?

Comment: So the problem is only when I copy with C-c, and paste (no matters how) to another application. copied text is not pasted right, pasted previously copied (not this way) text. And yes when I do copy by pressing it in menu then paste it to another application it pastes exactly what I copied. yet I didn't tested it without CUA mode. Runnin linux & 23.4.2 emacs

Comment: Please test without CUA in that case, because at present you are presenting this as a problem with CUA, and it may not be related to that at all.

Comment: Same without cua, when I copy with Esc-w I can paste it only to emacs.

Comment: I've rewritten your question for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html), section [25.1.5 Using the Clipboard](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html):

> You can customize the variable `x-select-enable-clipboard` to make the Emacs yank functions consult the clipboard before the primary selection, and to make the kill functions to store in the clipboard as well as the primary selection. Otherwise, these commands do not access the clipboard at all.

You should probably also read section [25.1.3 Cut and Paste with Other Window Applications](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Cut_002fPaste-Other-App.html).

Comment: save-interprogram-paste-before-kill 
x-select-enable-clipboard-manager
select-enable-clipboard/select-enable-primary and mouse-drag-copy-region

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your .emacs `(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)`